# cc of SendGrid not working in Azure Mobile app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

Only the below syntax seems to work in the Azure Mobile app as explained here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-mobile-services-send-email-scripts/#comment-2539027195

sendgrid.send({
      to: '**email-address**',
      from: '**from-address**',
      subject: 'New to-do item',
      text: 'A new to-do was added: ' + item.text
   }, function(success, message) {
      if (!success) {
      console.error(message);
   }
});

As can be seen above, the callback function has success parameter passed in whereas the node.js module in GitHub (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs) has error parameter instead. So it seems Azure mobile service is not using the same module or version, there is some disconnect there as well.

sendgrid.send(email, function(err, message) {
   if (err) {
      console.error(message);
   }
});

Comment: Could you share your related code for analyzing the issue?

Comment: sendgrid.send({ to: 'email-address', cc: 'email-address', from: 'from-address', subject: 'New to-do item', text: 'some text' }, function(success, message) { if (!success) { console.error(message); } });

Answer (score 3):

From the post on Azure Mobile Forums:

As the default version of SendGrid in Mobile Service is "0.2.4" which is much lower than the latest one.

There are 2 approaches you can follow to try to update the version of sendgrid in mobile service:

1, Sign in the kudu console site of your mobile service, leverage the cmdlet online on the site to modify the `package.json` file of your mobile service application, e.g.:

```
"sendgrid":"^2.0.0",
```

under the "dependencies" closure. Then run command : `npm update` in the cmdlet to update the sendgrid sdk in mobile service. The Kudu console site URL should be `https://<your_mobile_service_name>.scm.azure-mobile.net/DebugConsole`

2, You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-store-scripts-source-control/#use-npm to deploy the sendgrid sdk for your own, and use

```
var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')('YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY');
```

in your code to implement sendgrid.